# Plugins working in Eclipse Indigo, not in galileo

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-3.5

I developed an eclipse plugins. When i created the project, i provide the eclipse version to be supported 3.2 and above. The plugin is working perfectly in indigo. But, not working in Galileo.

plugins.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<plugin>

<extension
         id="wizard"
         name="SubApp Config"
         point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
      <category
            name="SubApp CodeGen"
            id="wizard.category1">
      </category>
      <wizard
            name="SubApp CodeGen"
            icon="icons/wizard.gif"
            category="wizard.category1"
            class="com.xyz.code.generator.wizard.SubAppWizard"
            id="wizard.wizard1">
         <description>

         </description>
      </wizard>
</extension>



</plugin>
```

Manifest.MF

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: com.xyz.article.wizards
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.citi.code.generator;singleton:=true
    Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
    Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
     org.eclipse.core.runtime,
     org.eclipse.core.resources,
     org.eclipse.jdt.core,
     org.eclipse.jdt.ui,
     org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.4.1",
     com.citi.code.generator.flavor;bundle-version="1.0.0",
     org.apache.velocity;bundle-version="1.5.0"
    Bundle-ClassPath: .
    Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5,
     JavaSE-1.6
```

Please help

Comment: how it is not working? you might consider asking in eclipse community as well

Comment: Go to your workspace folder, open .metadata and look to see what the error is and paste it on here.

Comment: Could it be a Java issue? I think Indigo requires java 1.6 and Galileo may not support it. Try to change execution environment to 1.5 and recompile and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment of Fredrik,

```
I think Indigo requires java 1.6 and Galileo may not support it. Try to 
change execution environment to 1.5 and recompile and see if that changes
anything.
```

Change the execution environment to 1.5 and set JAVA SDK to Java 1.5.

It solves the problem. Thanks